# Subset data by groups for duplicate records

Tags: r, duplicates, subset

I have a sample dataset like the following:

```
PID=numeric(101:110)
Subject_ID=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
status=c("Active","Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Withdrawn", "Withdrawn", "Withdrawn", "Active")
mydata=data.frame(PID, Subject_ID, status)
```

I would like to essentially create three data subsets with all of the source data (including duplicate Subject_ID): 1) Subject_ID with all active status 2) Subject_ID with all withdraw status 3)Subject_ID with both active and withdraw status. Identical Subject_IDs must all appear in the same group.

So far, my thinking is to create dummy variable for Status and sum this derived variable to breakdown the different groups.

```
mydata$Status_Code [((mydata$status=="Active"))] <- "0" #11414
mydata$Status_Code [((mydata$status=="Withdrawn"))] <- "1" #386
mydata$Status_Code=as.numeric(mydata$Status_Code)

DT=data.table(mydata)
DT[, Flag := as.numeric((sum(Status_Code))), by=Subject_ID]
```

This is my desired output - I want three separate tables (Groups of subject_id must in the same subset and only appear in one subset)

First Table:

```
PID=c(101, 102, 103, 104, 110)
Subject_ID=c(1, 1, 1, 1,  4)
status=c("Active","Active", "Active", "Active", "Active")
active=data.frame(PID, Subject_ID, status)
```

Second Table:

```
PID=c(108, 109)
Subject_ID=c(3, 3)
status=c("Withdrawn", "Withdrawn")
withdrawn=data.frame(PID, Subject_ID, status)
```

Third Table

```
PID=c(105, 106, 107)
Subject_ID=c(2, 2, 2)
status=c("Active","Active", "Withdrawn")
mixed=data.frame(PID, Subject_ID, status)
```

I assume there is probably an easier way to create these subsets other than summing the dummy variable.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your desired output and what are you trying to do. Can you show us the final product?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I have edited the original post with the desired outcome.